# Error when trying to subtract from non-object

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying get the total difference in minutes from when a database opens and closes within a given period of time. When my database contains more opening times than closing times, or vice versa, I get an error because it tries to subtract an opening time from a closing time that doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to ignore the remaining times that don't have a match?

PHP

```
$closing = "SELECT log_time FROM log_table WHERE database_name = '$d' AND server_protocol = '98' AND log_date >= '$from_date' AND log_date < '$to_date' ORDER BY log_date DESC, log_time DESC";
 $query = $this->db->prepare($closing);
 $query->execute();
 $closing_time = $query->fetchAll();

 $opening = "SELECT log_time FROM log_table WHERE database_name = '$d' AND server_protocol = '94' AND log_date >= '$from_date' AND log_date < '$to_date' ORDER BY log_date DESC, log_time DESC";
 $query = $this->db->prepare($opening);
 $query->execute();
 $opening_time = $query->fetchAll();

foreach ($opening_time as $o) {
     print "<pre>";
     print "------OPENING TIME -----";
     print_r($o);
     print "</pre>";
     }
foreach ($closing_time as $c) {
     print "<pre>";
     print "------CLOSING TIME -----";
     print_r($c);
     print "</pre>";
     }
```

Output

```
FMServer_Sample
------OPENING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 14:42:51
)
 ------OPENING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 13:24:36
)
------OPENING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
     [log_time] => 10:19:58
)
------CLOSING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
     [log_time] => 15:02:21
)
------CLOSING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
     [log_time] => 14:54:21
)
------CLOSING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 14:20:25
)
------CLOSING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 12:08:04
)

iCDS
------OPENING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 14:40:00
)
 ------OPENING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
    [log_time] => 13:00:00
)
------CLOSING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
     [log_time] => 14:50:00
)
------CLOSING TIME -----stdClass Object
(
     [log_time] => 13:10:00
)
```

And when I try to subtract the closing times from the opening times with this...

```
$result = 0;
for ($x = 0; $x < count($closing_time); $x++) {
     if ($closing_time != "" && $opening_time != "") {
           $result += (strtotime($closing_time[$x]->log_time) -strtotime($opening_time[$x]->log_time));
      }
}
$result = round($result / 60);
```

I get errors and a way-off number for the second set of times for which the result should be 20.

Errors

```
Notice: Undefined offset 19
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

iCDS 23377537 //should be 20
```

Comment: You're using the same iterator for $closing_time and $opening_time but only basing if off the count of $closing_time. Can you guarantee they have the same number of elements?

Comment: no, that's just it, sometimes they don't have the same number of elements, and I'm not sure how to set it so it doesn't error out when that happens

Comment: You could use isset() to check and default to something like `isset($closing_time[$x]) ? $closing_time[$x] : 0`

Comment: also, should't your log_date < '$to_date' be log_date <= '$to_date' ?

Comment: i'll try isset, but for the log_date I don't want anything included in the current day